# Using WPF dependency property between two projects

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I'm kinda new to the WPF world. 
I have two projects, in one I define a dependency property and binding it to a checkBox. 
In the other I want to read the property value (true/false) and act accordingly. 
I cannot reference dlls from the first project in the second.

Someone told me there's a way to get the property value in runtime from one WPF to the other.

Anyone has another clue?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, as there are WPF tools out there to help you debug WPF applications which let you view and modify properties from another WPF application. See if you can find source code for [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) or [WPF Inspector](http://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/) and look for how they do it.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at Snoop :)